# Do I need to unsubscribe each time onDestroy in component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering If I subscribe to stream in my constructor like this:

```
_eventEmitterService.event.subscribe((msg)=>{})
```

So when I change the view to different component, and come back, the events are triggered twice from that stream. Do I need to unsubscribe each time I change the component, by using `ngOnDestroy`?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you do. I would have given you the link where it states that in the documentation, but I cannot find it any more

Comment: Check this answer about when to unsubscribe https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732897/3100587

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found it! And yes, per documentation as stated in the angular2 [`lifecycle-hook`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) guide:

> **ngOnDestroy**
>   Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks.

So yes, you need to unsubscribe from observables on `ngOnDestroy()`

Answer (score 5):

Just an additional hint to the Pierre's great answer. The `async` pipe automatically unsubscribes observables it's applied on. So you need to unsubscribe for observables you manage by your own.

See this line in source code:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L74

Comment: Github link is dead now. Could you expand a little bit more, your answer seems to contradict Pierre a bit, so I'm unsure when I need to manually cleanup? Angular official tutorial doesn't do any cleanups as far as I can see.